# How to use `generator=1` to rebuild `build.ninja` files?

Tags: build, ninja

Can you clarify how to use `generator=1` to rebuild the `build.ninja` files? I haven't been able to find a clear explanation of the usage, or any examples.

In my case, I have a simply python script that generates the `build.ninja`.  It needs to be invoked whenever A) new source files are created (or deleted) OR B) the Python script itself changes.  I can do that manually.  But it seems I can somehow tell ninja to do this, by making the `build.ninja` file a target itself, dependent on the `generator.py` (and source files? not sure how to find those in ninja). How do I do that?

Also: If `build.ninja` changes due to ninja, will ninja reload its own `build.ninja` file?

Perhaps I am misunderstaning the paradigm here.  If I'm wrong, do I simply need to manually invoke `generator.py` whenever there are new files added? For multiple developers, should they invoke `generator.py` manually whenever they pull from git?